# Interpreting asan stack-buffer-underflow report

Tags: gcc, stack, address-sanitizer, red-zone

Today we've encountered an stack buffer underflow reported by gcc 10.2 && gcc 11 asan.

Looking into asan's output, we found that it points to following shadow byte pattern:

```
 someaddr =>  [f1]f1 f3 f3 f3
where
  f1 is stack left redzone
  f3 is stack right redzone.
```

It looks suspicious to me that there are no addressable bytes between stack left and right red zones. Could you please explain under what circumstances can such shadow layout occur?

Comment: Indeed, this means you have a zero-length object on stack. Do you have a small repro?

Comment: Unfortunately no, we tried to extract a minimum example, but it still includes quite a few pieces of internal logic.